# Counting and showing Duplicates in DataTable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am having issues with trying to count / show duplicate records in a Datatable.

for example I have a Datatable with multiple columns.

eg

```
Item (Colum1) |

111

112

113

111

112

112

112

114
```

I want to try and create another Datatable form this that outputs the following

```
Item (Colum1) | Counter (Colum2)

111             2

112             4

113             1

114             1
```

Answer (score 0):

So the query selects the results in the first column and groups them together so that you get one row per unique item number. The second column is the number of occurrences of that item number.

`SELECT Colum1 as Item, COUNT(Colum1) AS Counter FROM tablename
GROUP BY Colum1;`

Comment: Thanks for the information ProGramer, But I need the code written in VB.net

Comment: Why do you NEED it in VB.NET when the query can do it for you?